# Why's the button "Commit" greyed out in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

I want to commit my changes to my project to `GitHub` but for some reason, the "Commit" button is greyed out in `Android Studio`.  I can't seem to spot what's causing this issue.  Even when I write a message, it's still greyed out.

How would I fix this?

[image: Image of greyed out button]

Comment: Probably because you didn't select anything to be commited and didn't write a commit message.

Comment: @tkausl Even when I write a message, it's still greyed out.  Should've mentioned that in my post.

Comment: Your capture don't show any file selected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure those files are blue (or green if new files). Hit Cancel, go back out to the app. Right click app at the top and goo down to git then add all. That will add all of them. Then, you will be able to commit and push your changes. However, you also need to make sure you click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add files you want to commit:

```
git add <file_name>
```

or to add all of them:

```
git add .
```

Commit files (using IDE or console - for now button should be active):

```
git commit -m "message"
```

Commit files using IDE - remember add message to commit

Answer (score 0):

If there are files with red color mean you have not added them to git.
[Right click on the file->Git->add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt1Mu.png)

Then you can commits the changes.